# Can not get UDP packets

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am trying to get UDP packets ,sent by device via WiFi, on my pc.
The device (kind of card) send every 2 seconds new packet.
The problem is that i do not get the packets on java client i have on my pc.
I see the packets on Wireshark.

Here is my UDP client (java):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        int port = 80;

        // Create a socket to listen on the port.
        DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        dsocket.setSoTimeout(10000);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

        // Create a packet to receive data into the buffer
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        // Now loop forever, waiting to receive packets and printing them.
        while (true) {
            // Wait to receive a datagram
            try
            {
                dsocket.receive(packet);
            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                continue;
            }
            // Convert the contents to a string, and display them
            String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
            System.out.println(packet.getAddress().getHostName() + ": "+ msg);
            // Reset the length of the packet before reusing it.
            packet.setLength(buffer.length);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are receiving data?

Comment: I see the packet in wireshark
The source is 192.168.16.180 ,port 49879.
The dest is 192.168.16.255, port 80

Comment: @hajaji have you tried to send an UDP packet to a local IP address of your PC, instead of the broadcast address? Do you run wireshark in promiscuous mode?

Comment: I did sent and received packets from local server (in my PC),
and it work fine.
I even manage to do the same  with android device with WiFi connection.
What is promiscuous mode?
How can i set it?